# Recognizing page numbers in scanned PDF image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have a lot of PDFs, which are basically scanned documents or books, so each PDF page has two scanned images and I have to split those pages and organize according to the number of pages that was written on the page for printing. Page splitting is not a problem(I'm using the mutool poster), the problem is: "How can I detect the page number from the PDF part of the page (image)?

Here's an example of a page

[image]

I have tried with python + opencv + tesseract but no results because i can't detect the right position of the number(it can be in any corner) or if opencv detect the position then tesseract can't detect the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale and invert image
- Dilate to obtain letters as a single contour
- Find contours
- Crop the ROI of each contour and throw into Pytesseract
- If the result is a digit then save ROI

---

Convert to grayscale and invert image

```
image = cv2.imread('2.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray
```

[image]

Now we dilate to connect letters/contours together. The idea is that the page number contour will be separate from other characters on the page even though it could be in any corner

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=4)
```

[image]

From here we find contours and then extract the ROI. We throw each ROI into Pytesseract. If the returned result is all numbers then we have detected the page number ROI so we can save it with Numpy slicing

```
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
    if data.isdigit():
        print('Page #: ', data)
        cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
        image_number += 1
```

[image]

Here's the result from Pytesseract and the extracted ROI

[image]

> Page #:  110

Full code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('2.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=4)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
    if data.isdigit():
        print('Page #: ', data)
        cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
        image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hello, [nathancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11162165/nathancy), everything went well, until I found a document with this type of page numbers  [link page number](https://res.cloudinary.com/dkqhjakky/image/upload/v1567430433/Numbe_kjck1y.png).  , opencv detects bbox, but tesseract does not detect the text, what could I do? can you help me, please?

Comment: One thing you could do is once you extract the bbox and get a ROI, you can try morphological operations such as erosion to get rid of the rectangular box. But it may also remove detail from the number. A 2nd approach is once you get the ROI, you can filter using contour area and extract the smallest contour which should be the number then throw it into tesseract